# sockaddr_in considerations when compiling for different endianess

Tags: c, linux, sockets, arm, powerpc

I'm currently writing a small socket code for some embedded systems, one has ARM and the other has PowerPC, as far as I know, ARM is little endian while PowerPC is big endian, my code is:

```
void foo() {
  ...declarations here...
  struct sockaddr_in socket_address = {0};

  socket_descriptor = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

  socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  socket_address.sin_port = htons(9100);

  call_result = connect(socket_descriptor, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(socket_address));


 ...clean ups........
}
```

the code works when compiled for ARM, however it fails when compiled for PowerPC, the connect() function in particular returns -1, I am suspecting this has something to do with assigning inet address and port, and the endianess of the platforms, was there something i missed when i compiled for PowerPC

Comment: "ARM is big endian while PowerPC is small endian" No... ARM supports either but defaults to little endian. PowerPC tends to support either but defaults to big endian.

Comment: My bad, I will update.

Comment: Anyway, nothing in this code is endianess dependent as far as I can tell. You'll have to post something where the error can be reproduced. Could be caused by anything.

Comment: I'd live to, but it's proprietary in nature...

Comment: Tough luck. SO has a policy that questions asking "why is this code not working" must include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If nobody can reproduce the error, it seem unlikely that the question is answerable.

Comment: Is there something listening on port 9100 on your PowerPC?

Comment: "something listening on port 9100 on your PowerPC?"
that is guaranteed.

Comment: Does the command `telnet 127.0.0.1 9100` connect without problem?

Comment: yes it weirdly does, with a weird message.
"Escape character is '^]'."

Comment: Telnet's message is O.K. and your code looks O.K. as well.  Sorry, no other idea what is wrong here.

Comment: did you telnet from the powerpc to powerpc or arm to powerpc?  try the various combinations (server side on powerpc, telnet from power pc and arm, server side on arm, telnet from power pc and arm, doesnt run on arm is not an excuse if you have not solved the basic connection that is all the code you should have in the entire program for this experiment, on both sides).

Comment: What's `errno` set to after your failing `connect` syscall?